# Javascript Brainteaser - Reverse Number Determining

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a list of numbers in the following form(Ignore the `|` they are there for formating help).

```
00|00|xx
00|xx|00
xx|00|00
etc.
```

**Rules:** XX can be any number between 1 and 50.  No XX values can be identical.

Now I select a random set of numbers(no duplicates) from a list qualifying the above format, and randomly add and subtract them.  For example

`000011 - 002400 - 230000 =  -232389`

How can I determine the original numbers and if they were added or subtracted solely from **-232389**?  I'm stumped.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**
<s>I was looking for a function so I ended up having to make one.  Its just a proof of concept function so variables names are ugly http://jsfiddle.net/jPW8A/.</s>

There are bugs in the following implementation, and it fails to work in a dozen of scenarios.  Check the selected answer below.

```
function reverse_add_subtract(num){
    var nums = [];

    while(num != 0){
        var str = num.toString(),
            L = Math.abs(num).toString().length,
            MA = str.match(/^(-?[0-9]?[0-9])([0-9][0-9])([0-9][0-9])*$/);
        if(MA){
            var num1 = MA[1],
                num2 = MA[2];
        }else{
            var num1 = num,
                num2 = 0;
        }
        if(L%2)L++;
        if( num2 > 50){
            if(num < 0) num1--;
            else num1++;
        }
        nums.push(num1);
        var add = parseInt(num1 + Array(--L).join(0),10);
        num = (num-add);
    }
    return nums;
}
reverse_add_subtract(-122436);
```

Comment: homework?  some random code brainteaser?

Comment: A fun brainteaser.  I wish homework was like this though.  Precalc isn't nearly this fun or easy. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that each `xx` group is constrained from [1, 50). This implies that each associated pair in the number that is in the range [50, 99) is really 100 - `xx` and this means that it "borrowed from" the group to the left. (It also means that there is only one set of normalized numbers and one solution, if any.)

So given the input `23|23|89` (the initial `xx` spots from `-232389`), normalize it -- that is, starting from the right, if the value is >= 50, get 100 - value and carry the 100 rightward (must balance). Example: `(23 * 100) + 89 = 2300 * 89 = 2400 - 11 = 2389`. And example that shows that it doesn't matter if it's negative as the only things that change is the signs: `(-23 * 100) - 89 = -2300 - 89 = -2400 + 11 = -2389`

(Notes: Remember, 1 is added to the 23 group to make it 24: *the sign of the groups is not actually considered in this step*, the math is just to show an example that it's okay to do! It may be possible to use this step to determine the sign and avoid extra math below, but this solution just tries to find the candidate numbers at this step. If there are any repeats of the number groups after this step then there is no solution; otherwise a solution exists.)

The candidate numbers after the normalization are then `23|24|11` (let's say this is `aa|bb|cc`, for below). All the `xx` values are now known and it is just a matter of finding the combination such that `e * (aa * 10000) + f * (bb * 100) + g * (cc * 1) = -232389`. The values `aa`, `bb`, `cc` are known from above and `e`, `f`, and `g` will be either 1 or -1, respectively.

---

*Solution Warning:* A method of finding the addition or subtraction given the determined numbers (determined above) is provided below the horizontal separator. Take a break and reflect on the above sections before deciding if the extra "hints" are required.

---

This can then be solved by utilizing the fact that all the `xx` groups are not dependent after the normalization. (At each step, try to make the input number for the next step approach zero.)

Example:

1. `-232389 + (23 * 10000) = -2389` (`e` is -1 because that undoes the `+` we just did)
2. `-2389 + (24 * 100) = 11` (likewise, `f` is -1)
3. `11 - (11 * 1) = 0` (0 = win! `g` is 1 and solution is `(-1 * 23 * 10000) + (-1 * 24 * 100) + (1 * 11 * 1)` = `-232389`)

Happy homeworking.

Comment: I was looking for a function, but I ended up making one

Answer (score 1):

First, your math is wrong.  Your leading zeros are converting the first two numbers to octal.   If that is the intent, the rest of this post doesn't exactly apply but may be able to be adapted.

```
11-2400-230000 = -232389
```

Now the last number is easy, it's always the first two digits, `23` in this case.  Remove that:

```
-232389 + 230000 = -2389
```

Your 2nd number is the next `100` below this, `-2400` in this case.  And your final number is simply:

```
-2389 + 2400 = 11
```

Comment: You can force it to use base-10 if you add the radix to `parseInt()`: `parseInt('001', 10)`. But that will force you to do a `string -> integer` conversion.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I head simply pasted it in console thinking it would ignore the leading zeros.  Value is now changed.  Also, But how do you determine if the number was added or subtracted?

Comment: sorry, didn't see the "randomly add or subtract" piece.  It's pretty simple, if the final number is negative, the last one was subtracted.  Remove the last one.  If it's now positive, the 2nd number was added.  remove it.

Comment: I was looking for a function that determines the numbers and whether the were added or subtracted.  You know the of numbers by dividing the digits by 2 and rounding up to the nearest whole number. **EDIT: I just got your above message, I'm attempting to right a function myself but help would be great.**

Comment: Sorry, you're on your own for the code.  I gave you the logic :)

Answer (score 0):

Aww!  Someone posted an answer saying "brute force it" that I was about to respond to with:

```
function find(num){for(var i=1;i<50;i++){for(var o1=0;o1<2;o1++){for(var j=1;j<50;j++){for(var o2=0;o2<2;o2++){for(var k=1;k<50;k++){var eq;if(eval(eq=(i+(o1?'+':'-')+j+'00'+(o2?'+':'-')+k+'0000'))==num){ return eq; }}}}}}}
```

they deleted it... :(

It was going to go in the comment, but here's a cleaner format:

```
function find(num){
    for(var i=1;i<50;i++){
        for(var o1=0;o1<2;o1++){
            for(var j=1;j<50;j++){
                for(var o2=0;o2<2;o2++){
                    for(var k=1;k<50;k++){
                        var eq;
                        if(eval(eq=(i+(o1?'+':'-')+j+'00'+(o2?'+':'-')+k+'0000'))==num){ return eq; }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I saw the question to and had attempted to respond with this: The etc. was suppose to imply a continuing pattern of numbers `00|00|xx, 
00|xx|00, xx|00|00, XX|00|00|00, XX|00|00|00|00`

Comment: well you can still brute force that.  ___RECURSIVE___ brute force! ^_^